# Ticks and Labels at different positions in axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a figure in which I'd like to have labels and also ticks in the x-axis but at different positions. However, it seems that after setting the first ticks, when trying to define new ticks the previous ones are "forgotten". For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]
ys = [2.0, 1.667, 2.0, 0.333, 1.0, 0.667, 1.667, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

# where we want our labels
ticks1 = [5.0, 15.0, 25.0]
labs = ['A', 'B', 'C']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xs, ys)

# I think I have to define ticks here to position the labels...
ax.set_xticks(ticks1)
ax.set_xticklabels(labs)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So far is good, with the wanted arrangement. `ABC` are used to mark different groups of data points, and they are more or less in the middle of each respective group (I'll add vertical lines afterwards to make this separation more obvious), but ticks should reflect the data, not these artificial labels.

But if I try to now add a different set of ticks to the same axis, the labels plotted above migrate to the new ticks and do not keep their old position:

```
# ...but want to have ticks for this range
ticks2 = [x for x in range(0, 33, 3)]
ax.set_xticks(ticks2)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

What is the correct way to achieve the desired output in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matplotlib axes are ticked via locators and formatters. A locator tells the axis where to put ticks. A formatter puts a label at those ticks.

When using `ax.set_xticks` you are creating a `FixedLocator`, i.e. a set of fixed locations to tick.
When using `ax.set_xticklabels` you are creating a `FixedFormatter`, i.e. a set of fixed strings to place one by one on the ticks.

When you set the new ticks via `ax.set_xticks(ticks2)` you did not change the formatter. It will still format the first three ticks with the strings from its list.
This is to say: You would also need to set the new ticklabels for the changed case.

E.g. via

```
ax.set_xticklabels(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
```

Now if you want to have ticks at other positions than labels, this essentially means that you need two pairs of locators and formatters.

One locator-formatter pair would tick the multiples of 3, and use empty strings as labels. The other pair would tick 5,15,25, and set their labels to A,B,C.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]
ys = [2.0, 1.667, 2.0, 0.333, 1.0, 0.667, 1.667, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xs, ys)

# Major ticks
ticks2 = [x for x in range(0, 33, 3)]
ax.set_xticks(ticks2)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which="major", length=5)

# Minor ticks
ticks1 = [5.0, 15.0, 25.0]
labs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ax.set_xticks(ticks1, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(labs, minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which="minor",length=0)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But I want to have something the opposite of that, ie. keeping the same 'ABC' labels as from the first call but then add the new ticks while not labelling it again, in order to keep 'ABC' on their first position

Comment: That sounds weird to me. The initial positions were `5, 15, 25`, the new positions are multiples of `3`, which means the initial positions 5 and 25 are not even there anymore, and hence cannot be ticked.

Comment: So `5, 15, 25` would be for the labels but multiples of 3 for the ticks, I guess this would need 2 different formatters?

Comment: Two different sets of (Locator+Formatter). Mind they always come in pairs.

Comment: Yep, (Locator+Formatter) for the labels and a **different** (Locator+Formatter) for the ticks. Not sure if this is even possible but thought matplotlib could be flexible with this.

Comment: Looks quite strange to me.